# How to handle/ignore missing keys in json file?

Tags: python, json

This my below code. It works if the file paths and name1/2/3 under hotel_config are defined and written inside the json_updater. But if I don't put name2 and location_medailia, the code will just throw an error and won't update any paths. Is there a way I can bypass this error or tell it to ignore it? And just update the locations if they are given inside the json_updater.

```
def password_updater_HotelsTAG(self,hotel_ID,pwd):
        with open('Json_updater.json','r',encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
            json_updater_info = commentjson.load(f)        #takes the information from Json_updater.json
            password = pwd
            for i in json_updater_info["Hotel_Config"]:
                if i["Hotel_ID"] == str(hotel_ID):
                    file_name = i["name"]
                    file_name2 =i["name2"]
                    file_name3 =i["name3"]

                    try:
                        with open(f"{i['location_Daily']}\\{file_name}",'r') as f:
                            print("Updating file: " , file_name)

                            json_info = commentjson.load(f) #Gets info from the json file
                            json_info['hotels'][0]['password'] = password
                            print("location_Daily exists")
                            with open(f"{i['location_Daily']}\\{file_name}",'w') as f:
                                commentjson.dump(json_info,f,indent = 4) #updates the password   
                                print("location_Daily password updated")
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        print("location_Daily file not found...Please check the path again")
                    try:
                        with open(f"{i['location_Medallia']}\\{file_name2}",'r') as f:
                            print("Updating file: " , file_name2)
                            json_info = commentjson.load(f) #Gets info from the json file
                            json_info['password'] = password
                            print("location_Medallia exists")
                            with open(f"{i['location_Medallia']}\\{file_name2}",'w') as f:
                                commentjson.dump(json_info,f,indent = 4) #updates the password   
                                print("location_Medallia password updated")
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        print("location_Medallia file not found...Please check the path again")

                    try:
                        with open(f"{i['Third_location']}\\{file_name3}",'r') as f:
                            print("Updating file: " , file_name3)
                            json_info = commentjson.load(f) #Gets info from the json file
                            json_info['password'] = password
                            print("Third Location exists")
                            with open(f"{i['location_Medallia']}\\{file_name3}",'w') as f:
                                commentjson.dump(json_info,f,indent = 4) #updates the password   
                                print("location_Medallia password updated")
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        print("Third Location not found file not found...Please check the path again")
```

Json_updater.json:

```
{
  "Hotel_Config": [
      {

        "name": "test.json",
        "location_Daily": "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\Projects\\BOT\\Configs\\",
        "name2": "test.json",
        "location_Medallia": "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\Projects\\BOT2\\Configs\\",
        "name3": "test",
        "Third_location": "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\Projects\\BOT3\\Configs\\",
        "Hotel_ID": "1"
       #this works, no errors
      },
      {

        "name": "test.json",
        "location_Daily": "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\Projects\\BOT\\Configs\\",
        "name2": "test.json",
        "location_Medallia": "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\Projects\\BOT2\\Configs\\",
        "Hotel_ID": "1"
       #this does not work. Throws error
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict's get method. Like this:

```
file_name = i.get("name", "")
file_name2 = i.get("name2", "")
file_name3 = i.get("name3", "")
if file_name:
    pass
if file_name2:
    pass
if file_name3:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the get method to solve this (https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) or a try except block.